# Is it possible to use Spring Cloud Config to pass complex config to a spring cloud stream function

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config

I have a configuration that is an XML file that may be updated at any time.  I need to use it in a reactive function that I am using in the cloud data stream.  I was looking into storing it in spring cloud-config and I had a few questions

1. From the documentation it looks like spring cloud-config is used to store data I would see normally in a property file.  Can I store entire XML files in it?
2. In a function that I use with cloud stream 3.0 can I get the current value of the configuration with a @Value annotation?  For example

```
@Bean
    public Function<Flux<List<Record>>, Flux<Object>> doWork(@Value("test") String test)
```

and test would always have the current value of the XML file from the configuration store.

Answer (score 0):

Reactive functions are only invoked once during the initialisation time to effectively setup a stream. It is different than imperative functions that Are event driven.
So anything that is passed to it via method signature will only represent whatever the value was during that time.

Comment: Thanks if I added @RefreshScope to the bean would it get reinvoked when the /refresh endpoint is invoked?

Comment: No, it would not. But I think you're missing a bigger picture here. If you want some kind of per-message property access, then you can simply use non-reactive function which will be invoked on each message. Reactive functions are not for this type of use case.